Overleaf does not find cls file using latexmkrc
Currently, I try to use my own class file in an overleaf project.
My minimal example consists of main.tex, latexmkrc and the needed cls-file template/mybook.cls.
For the minimal example, I just took the cls from ctan.
My main.tex is:
\documentclass{mybook}
\title{Layout Test}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  Some Text
\end{document}

The latexmkrc file tries to include the template directory as follows:
ensure_path('TEXINPUTS', './template//' );

In the settings, I selected LuaLaTeX (but also tried LaTeX and pdfLaTeX).
So, basically I used everything as described in the documentation. I tried the version given by the overleaf documentation itself and another mentioned here. My minimal example here uses the latter one.
The compiler just says: LaTeX Error: File `mybook.cls' not found.
For completeness I added the full log:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.6.20)  18 JUL 2024 12:01
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>

! LaTeX Error: File `mybook.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.2 ^^M
       
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 20 strings out of 473600
 412 string characters out of 5728708
 1925905 words of memory out of 12435455
 22995 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 19i,0n,29p,62b,17s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

So my question is, what do I wrong?

This works for me on Overleaf.

I was already thinking something like that. So the problem seems to lie with our overleaf instance. Unfortunately, I can't get any more useful information from the logs. How can I proceed at this point, apart from not using overleaf? It's just quite useful to keep working with lots of people.

I'd first double check that the project is actually set up exactly as it is supposed to be, with exactly the filenames that are intended. (I can provoke the error you showed by mis-spelling the name of the .cls file.) After that, you could ask Overleaf for help; that's the job of their support staff.

Thank you. Then I will close this topic.
